# Elixir/Phoenix framework how to remove css

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to remove all the standard styles, then add my own. I deleted all files from the folder assets/css and after that restarted the server - previous styles remain. Then I also deleted the styles from the folder priv/static/css and after that restarted the server - previous styles remain. Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong and how to add/remove CSS correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the import of the necessary CSS to the assets/js/app.js

```
import "../css/test.css"
```

I don’t know how correct this solution is, but it works.

Comment: This is correct. When you just removed the files, you probably forgot to remove the import in your `app.js` file for it. Which would mean webpack would fail to build your assets because it couldn't find something. Which lead to the "old" assets still being there. Now that you have replaced the import, webpack is properly building again and you are seeing your new styles correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `node_modules/.cache` and you should be good.